# Can't get JQuery to append some html and a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a script to keep a history track of three for a random number generator. (this is all for practice to take more advance approach) but I for some reason cannot get jQuery to Append a new html table/row after the code starts executing from a different JS file. however everything seems to go according to plan besides the part when I am trying to add the row into the table. I have a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/e3ey2a3s/2/

Here is my code however:

```
convert.js (the generator)
 var min, max, setDol = false,
   pArry = [];

function chooseRandom() {
    min = prompt('whats the max value?', 'max');
    max = prompt('whats the min value?', 'min');
    return convertType(min, max);
}

function convertType(min, max) {
    if (typeof min === 'string' || typeof max === 'string') {
        document.getElementById('convert').innerHTML = "converting strings to numbers..."
        parseInt(min);
        parseInt(max);
    }
    return getRandom(min, max);
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
    if (isNaN(min) || isNaN(max)) {
        borked();
    } else {
        return amtFixed(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }
}

function amtFixed(amt) {
    if (amt >= 0 && amt <= 10) {
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Our number is " + amt + " which is between 0 and 10";
    } else if (amt >= 11 && amt <= 20) {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Our number is " + amt + " which is between 11 and 20";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Our number is " + amt + " which is greater than 20. huh.";
    }

    var fixed = Number(amt).toFixed(2);
    return convertFix(fixed);
};

function convertFix(fixed) {
    if (typeof fixed === 'string') {
        fixed = (fixed / 1);
        document.getElementById("fixed").innerHTML = typeof fixed + " " + fixed + " converted down to two decimals.";
        setDol = confirm("Convert our amount to a dollar amount?");
    } else {
        console.log('Failed to convert...');
    }
    return success(fixed);
};

function borked() {
    var broke = false;
    alert("You must not of entered a proper number... That sucks :/");
    var broke = confirm("Do you want to retry?");
    if (broke) {
        return chooseRandom();
    } else {
        return document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "I r broked :(";
    }
}

function success(num) {
    var amtHist = [];
    if (setDol) {
        $("#price").append('$' + num + ' Set fixed to a dollar amount!');
        pArry.push(num);
        return buildHistory(pArry);
    } else {
        $("#price").empty().append("Our fixed value is: " + num);
        pArry.push(num);
        return buildHistory(pArry);
    }
}
```

After this script finishes up `success()` send the finished array over to my `data.js` function `buildHistory()` which looks like this:

```
 buildHistory = function(arr) {
    var t, i, _this = this,
        numEls = 0,
        a = arr;
    var objLen = holdObj.History.length;
    table = $('table.history');
    //Let's do our loops to check and set history data
    //We need to get our history data so we can make sure not to re print old data.
    for (t = 0; t <= objLen; t++) {
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            x = objLen[t];
            if ($.inArray(x, a) === -1) {
                    //Alright now we build onto the history table
                $('table.history').append('<tr><td>' + a[i] + '</td></tr>');
                var cell = table.find('td');
                cell.addClass('hist' + numEls);
                numEls++;
                holdObj.History.push(a[i]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Let's remove the oldest value once the table exceeds 3 or 4.
        if (objLen > 3 && numEls > 3) {
            var tmp = table.find('hist_3');
            table.remove(tmp);
            holdObj.History.pop();
        }
}
```

This is all still in the makes so nothing is really finalized here, I am probably just overlooking a simple solution.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/libs/jQuery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This is just some filler content lol.</p>
        <p>Let's run some scripts! Click the buttons!</p>

        <div class="math">
            <p id="convert"></p>
            <p id="text"></p>
            <p id="fixed"></p>
            <p id="price"></p>
            <table id="history">
            <tr>
                <th>History</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="hist"> Value #1</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <button class="scrBtn">Click to start Script</button>
        <div id="date"></div>
        <button class="dateBtn">Get Date</button>
        <div class="person">
            <div class="pTitle">
                <div class="pBody">
                    <div class="fName">Name: </div>
                    <div class="age">Age: </div>
                    <div class="height">Height: </div>
                    <div class="eyecolor">Eye Color: </div>
                    <div class="sex">Sex: </div>
                    This is where our person should go.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="view/Form/personForm.html">
            <button class="pBtn">Get Info</button>
        </a>
    <div class="bRowLeft">test

    </div>
    <div class="tRowLeft">test

    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/model/data.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/model/convert.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/model/button.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

</html>
```

Sorry for such a long post but I am trying to explore as much as I can.

(The code is activated via jQuery with button.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.scrBtn').click(function() {
        chooseRandom();
    });
});
```

Thanks again, let me know if anymore information is needed.

Comment: In `append()` you close <tr> before <td>

Comment: Nice spot dunno how but I didn't even see that. Thanks, however the issue still remains

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but using the fiddle link, I was getting all sorts of JavaScript errors from variables not being declared. ("int" inside the success function, and "holdObj" inside the buildHistory function) Is there any more code that is missing?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I was missing a variable and I had updated another but forgot to change it through success. I updated the link and it should be fixed. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('table.history')` - you dont have a `<table class="history">` element.

Try this:

```
table = $("#history");
```

and same where you append.

Comment: Gah, I feel stupid now for not realizing I used an ID instead of a class for whatever reason. Thank you for your help, works like a charm.